# Fermi level position in doped semiconductor

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, fermi-energy

Physically by increasing temperature, the semiconductor tends to be intrinsic as the number of free electrons genereted by thermal generation becomes comparable to free electrons due to doping till it becomes the dominant in semiconductor and the semiconductor becomes intrinsic.

So fermi level decreases untill it becomes intrinsic fermi level $E_{fi}$ or $E_i$ (intermediate between $E_c$ & $E_v$).

But why at first we begin with level intermediate between $E_{donor}$ and $E_c$?

[image]

Comment: Why is the intrinsic Fermi level halfway between the valence and conduction bands? Same reason. The donor states are filled at T=0, the conduction band is empty.